# How to generate all classes for all thrift files in the folder by single command?

Tags: java, thrift

Now I use following command for **each** file in the folder:

```
thrift-0.11.0.exe --gen java reswk-manager.thrift
```

It is really uncomfortable.

I know I can create bat script for file iterating but I am not prefer it.

Can I achieve it by sing command?

Comment: any reason the answer below is not accepted?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a thrift like make file, called build.thrift (or whatever) something like this:

```
include "a.thrift"
include "b.thrift"
include "./somedir/c.thrift"
include "./someotherdir/d.thrift"
```

and then run thrift with the -r switch to recursively build all of the dependencies:

> thrift -r -gen java build.thrift